# Show item, total price and total quantity in cart bag icon

Tags: python, django

Except my cart page, another page can't show item name, quantity and price on my web, this is my [Project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwm47.png).

**base.html**

```html
<div class="sinlge-bar shopping">
    <a href="#" class="single-icon"><i class="ti-bag"></i> 
    <span class="total-count">{{cart.get_total_product}}</span></a>
    <!-- Shopping Item -->
    <div class="shopping-item">
        <div class="dropdown-cart-header">
            <span>{{cart.get_total_product}} Items</span>
            <a href="{% url 'cart:cart_detail' %}">View Cart</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="shopping-list">
            {% for item in cart %}
            {% with product=item.product %}
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="remove" title="Remove this item"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
                <a class="cart-img" href="{% url 'store:product' product.pk %}"><img src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="{{item.product.name}}" width="100" height="100"></a>
                <h4><a href="{% url 'store:product' product.pk %}">{{item.product.name}}</a></h4>
                <p class="quantity">
                    {{item.quantity}}x
                    <span class="amount">{{item.price|floatformat:0|intcomma}}</span>
                </p>
            </li>
            {% endwith %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="total">
                <span>Total</span>
                <span class="total-amount">{{item.total_price|floatformat:0|intcomma}}</span>
            </div>
            <a href="{% url 'store:checkout' %}" class="btn animate">Checkout</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**store/url.py**

```py
app_name = 'store'
urlpatterns = [
    path ('',views.index, name='index'),
    path ('index.html',views.index, name='index'),
    path ('cart.html',views.cart_detail, name='cart'),
    path ('search.html',views.search_form, name='search'),
    path ('contact.html',views.contact, name='contact'),
    path ('checkout.html',views.checkout, name='checkout'),#/<int:pk>/
    path ('blog-single-sidebar.html',views.blog, name='blog'),
    path ('shop-grid.html/<int:pk>/',views.shop, name='shop'),
    path ('product.html/<int:pk>/',views.product_detail, name='product'),#/<int:pk>/
    path ('filter_by_prices.html',views.filter_by_prices,name='filter_by_prices')
]
```

I try to add `cart.py` to use function with code like this but not working

**store/views.py**

```py
from cart.cart import Cart


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    return render(request, 'store:cart.html', {'cart': cart})
```

It looks like following, except cart page:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm confused about what's working and what doesn't.  Where does it go wrong?

Comment: I just add image about my problem in end of my post, cart icon can't show the item, quantity and another info except i click to cart link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks you @Suhaib Illyas,
i fixed it, just need to add `Cart = Cart(request)` and context `{'cart': cart}` to another funtion in store.

Answer (score 0):

Run the query like this:

```py
def place_order(request, total=0, quantity=0,):
    current_user = request.user


    #if cartr count is less than or = 0 then redirect back to shop
    cart_items = Cart_item.objects.filter(user=current_user)
    cart_count = cart_items.count()
    if cart_count <= 0 :
        return redirect('store')
    
    grand_total = 0
    tax = 0
    for cart_item in cart_items:
        total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
        quantity += cart_item.quantity
    tax = (2 * total)/100

    context = {            
        'cart_items'    :cart_items,
        'total'         :total,
        'tax'           :tax,
        'grand_total'   :grand_total,
    }
```

and url pattern:

```py
path('place_order/', views.place_order, name='place_order')
```